# How to expire a caches_action with a cache_path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I'm caching an index action with the following:

```
caches_action :index, :cache_path => Proc.new { |c| c.params }

expire_action :action => :index
```

The expire_action seems to only expire the index action without any parameters.
How can I expire all the caches_action related to index ?

(it is a Rails 2.3.5 application)

Comment: Check out the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251992. I posted a solution to this issue there
.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not using memcached, you can use expire_fragment with a regexp:

```
expire_fragment(Regexp.new("/yourpath/youraction\\."))
```

Comment: I don't get it. What's the link between `expire_fragment` and `expire_action`? How is it possible to expire the action for **every** `cache_path`? Thanks

Comment: I think it is because action caching uses fragment caching under the hood