# Expire action cache with custom cache_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, action-caching

I'm having some problem expiring an action cache in my application.

Here is my controller:

```
class ToplistsController < ApplicationController
  caches_action :songs, cache_path: :custom_cache_path.to_proc

  def custom_cache_path
    "#{params[:when]}-#{params[:what]}-#{params[:controller]}-#{params[:action]}"
  end

  def songs
    # ...
  end  
end
```

I somehow need to be able to reset the custom cache path, but I can't figure out how.

I've already tried using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965370/how-to-expire-a-caches-action-with-a-cache-path), without success. It looks like Dalli, which is my cache engine, doesn't support regexp matcher.

I'm getting this error when trying to use this code:

`expire_fragment(/songs/)`

`ActiveSupport::Cache::DalliStore does not support delete_matched`

I've tried to use this line of code, for debugging, but it's being ignored.

```
before_filter only: [:songs] 
  expire_fragment(custom_cache_path)
end
```

I'm using Rails 3.1.0.rc6, Dalli 1.0.5 and Ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: You you use a regex with dallicache with this gem: https://github.com/defconomicron/dalli-store-extensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `before_filter` block was ignored duo to the action cache.
The solution is to use a fragment cache instead.

```
# Controller
class ToplistsController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :custom_cache_path

  before_filter only: [:songs]
    if params[:reset_cache]
      expire_fragment(custom_cache_path)
    end
  end

  def custom_cache_path
    "#{params[:when]}-#{params[:what]}-#{params[:controller]}-#{params[:action]}"
  end

  def songs
    # ...
  end  
end

# View

<%= cache custom_cache_path do %>
  Content that should be cached
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check out the solution [here](http://broadcastingadam.com/2011/05/advanced_caching_in_rails).  With his approach you can expire actions with extra parameters.